# Ffmpeg merging videos from images with normal video + audio

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, audio-streaming

Using fluent-ffmpeg i'm making 3 videos from images and then i'm adding audio to them, then i'm merging them with a normal video that has it's own audio but i'm getting input pad error.

If i add audio to that normal video it works but how can i keep it's audio and merge them all without input pad error?

So i'm having an array of fragments which can be an image or a video, in our case we have 3 image fragments and 1 normal video fragment.
Here i'm creating videos from images with dinamic duration using loop().

```
let ffmpegInstance = ffmpeg(
        `./images/images-with-same-size/${fragment.filename}`
      );

      if (fragment.duration && fragment.type === "image") {
        ffmpegInstance.loop(fragment?.duration);
      }

      if (fragment.type === "image") {
        ffmpegInstance
          .addInput("./audio/audio.mp3")
          .inputOptions(
            "-ss",
            time,
            "-to",
            time + fragment.duration,
            "-async",
            "1"
          );

        time = time + fragment.duration;
        console.log("time:", time);
      }

      ffmpegInstance
        .videoCodec("libx264") // Codec from api
        .videoBitrate("12000k") // Video Quality
        .videoFilters([
          {
            filter: "fade",
            options: "in:0:15",
          },
        ]) // Transitions
        .on("error", function (err) {
          console.error("An error occurred: " + err.message);
        })
        .on("end", function () {
          res.write(`<p>Processing finished for ${fragment.filename}</p>`);
          fragment.filePath = `./output/project-${VIDEO_CONFIG.projectId}/videos/video-${fragment.filename}.avi`;

          callback(null, fragment);
        })
        .save(
          `./output/project-${VIDEO_CONFIG.projectId}/videos/video-${fragment.filename}.avi`
        );
```

So i added input audio to those videos made from images, but not added audio to the normal video because it has it's own audio. And then i'm merging all the videos made from images with that video that is the last fragment.

```
VIDEO_CONFIG.fragments
            .reduce((prev, curr) => prev.input(curr.filePath), ffmpeg())
            .outputFPS(60)
            .on("error", (err) => {
              res.end();
              console.log(
                `An error occurred while merging video files: ${err.message}`
              );
            })
            .on("end", () => {
              res.write("FINAL VIDEO END");
              res.end();
            })
            .mergeToFile(
              `./output/project-${VIDEO_CONFIG.projectId}/final-video-${VIDEO_CONFIG.projectId}.mp4`
            );
```

Then i'm getting this error `An error occurred while merging video files: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 7 on filter Parsed_concat_0.`

So i have 3 videos made from images which have video and audio input pads, so that means that when they merge the 4th video is input pad 7.

The thing is that if i addInput audio to that normal video, it works, but i loose it's initial audio. How can i bypass that? Please help, i'm trying to find a solution by a month now.

I just wanna know if it's possible to merge videos made from images + audio with another normal video that has it's own audio. If it's possible to create videos from images and add audio to them, i imagine that it can be merged with other videos that have their own audio.

Comment: How can we duplicate this issue so we can find out the problem? What are the actual errors?

Comment: @llogan i've updated the question with the code and info, thank you for helping.

Comment: I don't know anything about fluent, but in normal ffmpeg this error is from the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat). Some reasons it can occur: if one of your inputs does not contain an expected video or audio stream, or if you provide the wrong `n` value in the concat filter.

Comment: @llogan i tried this, but still getting input pad error.


``if (fragment.type === "video") {
     ffmpegInstance.complexFilter(["[0:v] concat=n=1:v=1:a=0"]);
 }``

I tried a=0 so it won't expect an input from it but it doens't work.

Comment: I don't understand why so many errors when trying to merge a video with input audio added and a normal video with it's own audio

Comment: I'm thinking on extracting the audio from the normal video and adding it back as an input to get rid of the error.